# TYPO3 page only shows "HELLO WORLD!"

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I started to learn how to use TYPO3 because I want to create a FAQ page. So I created a very simple page:

[image: FAQ Page]

But if I view the page, then i only get "**HELLO WORLD!**". What am i doing wrong?
Did i missed some steps? Where can i get started the best way?
I use TYPO3 8.1.2 btw.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: You have done nothing wrong.

TYPO3 has it's own configuration language: TypoScript.

You have to tell the system in TypoScript what should be rendered in the frontend. The default is a simple TypoScriptSnippet that only prints out the text HELLO WORLD.

I looks something like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = WELLO WORLD
```

You can find the configuration of your page in the Template module in the backend in the field "Setup". You can either change the TypoScript directly in there or use external files and include them.

You have to understand at least the basics of TypoScript and Templating in TYPO3 to make the content you create in the backend appear in the frontend. If you learn from sources in the internet, try to avoid the old ones.

If you need more help, please feel free to join the TYPO3 community at slack (https://forger.typo3.org/slack), where you can ask any kind of TYPO3 related questions. We will happyly hep you to get started.

Comment: I thought typo3 is for people who don't understand anything about scripting, but it is more complicated than i thought.

Comment: @EdwardBlack TYPO3 IS complicated, at least at beginning, anyway it gives you really powerful tools. You'll need at least several weeks at start to jump in.

Comment: So do i have to "enable" any element by hand so that it appears on the frontend?! Then i can also just go ahead and write everything in html and i am even quicker because i don't have to learn an extra script language... so im afraid typo3 is worthless for me.

Comment: Obviously that is not how TYPO3 works. But you won't get far without any effort. If you however understand the concepts of TYPO3 it enables you to achieve any kind of task your website might require.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add template typescript code.

or other best way is the use the template by install the template from the pre distribution option.

Go to file extension and select from drop down "Get Preconfigured distribution" option and install from their list of available template.

After install successfully you can see page add/edit option have web icon, inside them you can create new page, 
It will show page content on view.